# Input loses string format when running python from bash

Tags: python, string, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I log in through ssh and run bash. In these bash commands, I need to call a specific function in a python file and pass a string argument into this function.

What I have right now:

```
echo "commands" | ssh into instance
```

where commands contains

```
python -c 'from python file import myfunction;
            myfunction({}) ' ... .format(myvariable)
```

myvariable is a string containing multiple words.

However, when ssh completes and the commands are executed, debugging logs show that the quotes around myvariable are gone and when passed into myfunction, I get an error for undefined input variables.

How do I make sure myvariable stays a string?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may want to look into [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) instead of printing commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by thinking quotes are context aware. They're not.

Example:

```
var="select * from table where name="value" order by name"
```

As a human you might think that since this is a SQL statement, obviously bash will know that the quotes in the middle are nested, and will read the string like this:

```
var="select * from table where name="value" order by name"
                                    |-----| Nested
    |----------------------------------------------------| Everything
```

Bash, however, isn't that smart. It reads the string like this:

```
var="select * from table where name="value" order by name"
    |-------------------------------|     |--------------|
           Quoted string #1                   Quoted #2
```

The literal values are concatenated, with the net effect that the middle quotes "disappear". The statement is equivalent to:

```
var="select * from table where name=value order by name"
```

Instead, you have to tell bash that the quotes are literal data with escapes:

```
var="select * from table where name=\"value\" order by name"
```

[Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically warns about this.